# How to copy the Folderstructure with subfolders

Tags: python, path

how can i copy only the structure (excluding the files) of a path with all subfolders?

For example

```
path1\subfolder1\subsubfolder1
                \subsubfolder2
     \subfolder2\subsubfolder1
                \subsubfolder2
```

copy to

```
path2\subfolder1\subsubfolder1
                \subsubfolder2
     \subfolder2\subsubfolder1
                \subsubfolder2
```

I need this because i am loading pickles from path1 and calculating some things. The save need to be to a new path so i can compare the changes.
Already tried it with `path1.split('/')` but this only works if path1 is not changing so i need to change this everytime for new calculations if I want to change the pickles.

Comment: `find . -type d -print0 >dirs.txt` and `xargs -0 mkdir -p <dirs.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `os.walk` to recursively search through all sub folders for the given path.
Then for each subfolder found you can replace the input path with the output path and use the `os.makedirs` to create the folders if they do not exist yet.

```
import os

def copy_folder_structure(input_dir, output_dir):
    all_subfolders = [x[0] for x in os.walk(input_dir)]
    for folder in all_subfolders:
        output_folder = folder.replace(input_dir, output_dir)
        if not os.path.exists(output_folder):
            os.makedirs(output_folder)

copy_folder_structure("path1", "path2")
```